# Install FreeRADIUS - talloc library not found

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install the latest FreeRADIUS on CentOS 6.6. I'm getting this error:

```
[...]
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /opt/lib... no
configure: WARNING: talloc library not found. Use --with-talloc-lib-dir=<path>.
configure: error: FreeRADIUS requires libtalloc
```

I have already installed the necessary library (libtalloc). What can I do?

Other info that can be helpful:

```
pastebin.com/srjz7V0j - config.log
pastebin.com/YY2zSygb - configure cmd
Package libtalloc-2.0.7-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
FreeRADIUS 3.0.6
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, looks like I needed the libtalloc-devel package.

```
yum install libtalloc-devel -y
```

Solved! Thanks! :)

want to have a look on config.log? there you have it:

```
pastebin.com/3DfPTtVP
```

Comment: It would have been nice if the error message would have just said libtalloc-devel.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -LOk https://www.samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf talloc-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd talloc-2.1.0
./configure --without-gettext
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: You should edit your post to explain __why__ you're doing this.

Comment: + 1 needs to have detailed explanation as to the reason why you do it this way.